# C# Performance Counter - How to watching W3WP / Active Request?

Tags: c#, request, performancecounter, w3wp

I want to watch W3WP / Active Request with C#.NET, but W3WP / Active Request is invisible in the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate's Performance Counter Object.

How can I watch the active request at real time with C#? Is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](http://blogs.iis.net/mailant/archive/2008/01/10/new-worker-process-performance-counters-in-iis7.aspx), the best way to follow Requests/sec at worker process level is to follow the Counter called **Requests /Sec** in category **W3SVC_W3WP**. Specify instance name following the pattern **pid_apppool_name** or **_Total** if you don't know Pid/AppPoolName.